# getAttributeValue returns null java

Tags: java, xml, jdom

i want to get the vaule of type in root element.

if i try with getAttributeValue("type") it returns null value

here the sample xml and code. i'm using org.jdom2.Element for parsing
help will be appriciated.

Sample xml

```
<root type="new">
<msg size="30">

<attr uid="0" value="500" />
<attr uid="15" value="XHYs5"/>

</msg>
</root>
```

my code

```
        SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
        File xmlFile = new File(filename);

        Document document;
        try {
            document = (Document) builder.build(xmlFile);
        } catch (JDOMException | IOException e1) {
           throw new ISOException("Error reading xml file");
        }
        Element rootNode = document.getRootElement();
        typeVal=rootNode.getAttributeValue("type");  
        System.out.println(typeVal);
```

Comment: Use `rootNode.getAttribute("type")`

Comment: tried getAttribute() not working

Comment: Debug your application and see if `rootNode` is what you think it is.

Comment: What do you mean not working ?  first get the Attribute then call `getValue()`

Comment: nullpointer exception on getValue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you have bad `imports`. Your code works for me.

```
import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.Element;
import org.jdom2.JDOMException;
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DemoTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
        File xmlFile = new File("E:\\git\\src\\datamigrationGeneric\\test\\sample.xml");

        Document document = null;
        try {
            document = (Document) builder.build(xmlFile);
        } catch (JDOMException | IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        Element rootNode = document.getRootElement();
        String typeVal=rootNode.getAttributeValue("type");
        System.out.println(typeVal);

    }
}
```

Comment: import org.jdom2.Document;
import org.jdom2.Element;
import org.jdom2.JDOMException;
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;
import org.jdom2.output.XMLOutputter;
these are my imports

Comment: check you `sample.xml ` again. is there any syntax mismatch with type?? Or your path is not correctly assigned with the updated file.